# Tabs in string disappear when saved in variable

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on a bash script and originally had a line like this:

```
combined=`echo "$name"$'\t'"$phone"`
```

Then printed it out like this:

```
echo $combined >> file.txt
```

However, I discovered that the tabs are lost in this process. Here is a shortened example:

[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: In this case, there is no reason to individually quote your variables in `combined`. `combined='echo -e "$name\t$phone"'` will accomplish the same thing (**note:** `echo -e`) Or, using `printf` will provide `tab` expansion by default. `combined='printf "$name\t$phone\n"'` (or more properly `combined='printf "%s\t%s\n" "$name" "$phone"'`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because the shell is performing word splitting when passing the arguments to `echo`. This can be prevented by quoting the variable.

```
echo "$combined" >> file.txt
```

Comment: @choroba: Technically it's still a "substitution", even without transforming the variable's contents.

Comment: I'd rather use the word "expansion".

Answer (score 2):

why you're setting your variable thru `echo`?

I would set it directly:

```
combined="blubb\tblubb"
```

and then print it *(don't forget the **-e**)*:

```
echo -e $combined
```

so all in all your code snippet would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="blubb"
phone="1234"

combined="${name}\t${phone}"
echo -e $combined >> file.txt
```